# How can you access UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetatdata?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am receiving the info dictionary back that looks a little like this:

```
UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata =     {
        DPIHeight = 72;
        DPIWidth = 72;
        Orientation = 1;
        "{Exif}" =         {
            ApertureValue = "2.526068811667588";
            BrightnessValue = "-0.1108180525441177";
            ColorSpace = 1;
            DateTimeDigitized = "2014:03:26 00:19:41";
            DateTimeOriginal = "2014:03:26 00:19:41";
            ExposureMode = 0;
            ExposureProgram = 2;
            ExposureTime = "0.06666666666666667";
            FNumber = "2.4";
            Flash = 32;
            FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 35;
            FocalLength = "4.28";
            ISOSpeedRatings =             (
                640
            );
            LensMake = Apple;
            LensModel = "iPad back camera 4.28mm f/2.4";
```

I would like to know how I could get back DateTimeDigitized into a `NSString`? This is what I have tried

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = [info objectForKey:@"Exif"];
NSString *dateString = [dataDict objectForKey:@"DateTimeDigitized"];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", dateString, [dataDict objectForKey:@"DateTimeDigitized"]);
```

but everything comes back as nil.

Comment: Have you tried NSDictionary *dataDict = [info objectForKey:@"{Exif}"]; ?

Answer (score 0):

You've skipped the first key in the dictionary - UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString* dateString = [[[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] objectForKey:@"{Exif}"] objectForKey:@"DateTimeDigitized"];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
}
```